# LocalDateTime safes a null in my private attribute?

Tags: java, oop, datetime, null

I show you the code first.
First of all i will show my main class. I am not finished with my Programm I just wanna test whats in my attribute is saved. It saved 'null'.

```
public class Starter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Transaktion transaktion = new Transaktion();
    System.out.println(transaktion.getZeitStempel());
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());

}// end of main

}// end of class
```

That is my Transaktion class. This attribute "zeitstempel give me a null".

```
public class Transaktion {
/**
 * Deklaration von Attributen
 */
private LocalDateTime zeitStempel;
private Transaktionsart tart;
private String beschreibungstext;
private double betrag;


 public Transaktion(LocalDateTime zeitStempel, Transaktionsart tart, String beschreibungstext, double betrag) {
    super();
    this.zeitStempel = zeitStempel;
    this.tart = tart;
    this.beschreibungstext = beschreibungstext;
    this.betrag = betrag;
}

public Transaktion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public LocalDateTime getZeitStempel() {
    return zeitStempel;
}

public void setZeitStempel(LocalDateTime zeitStempel) {
    this.zeitStempel = zeitStempel;
}
```

Last class is the Menue that have an methode which initialize the attribut "zeitStempel".

```
public void transaktionslisteEinlesen(){

    String beschreibungstext = MeineEingabe.erfasseString("Beschreibungstext: ");
    double betrag = MeineEingabe.erfasseDouble("Betrag:");
    LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.now();

    Konto konto = new Konto();
    Transaktion transaktion = new Transaktion(localdatetime, null, beschreibungstext, betrag);

    konto.addTransaktion(transaktion);
}
```

Ignore the fact of the Konstructor null that is for an other attribute.

I hope you can help i tried so long the manage the null-value but i hate it.

Best Regards
GreenTea

Comment: for me it doesn't look like you ever call the method `transaktionslisteEinlesen`. also you call the empty constructor, which does nothing in you starter class

Comment: Your no-arg constructor only has a `// TODO` comment and doesn't assign any fields, and you confused that the fields are `null`? *Really?!?*

Answer (score 0):

You're using the empty constructor, and therefore never set the timestamp to anything.

You either need to call the `setZeitStempel` Or use the constructor with the parameters.

For the `einlesen` method you're using the correct constructor, but you never actually call it as far as I can see.

You could do something like this:

```
public Transaktion transaktionEinlesen(){

    String beschreibungstext = MeineEingabe.erfasseString("Beschreibungstext: ");
    double betrag = MeineEingabe.erfasseDouble("Betrag:");
    LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.now();


    return new Transaktion(localdatetime, null, beschreibungstext, betrag);
}
```

And then in `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Transaktion transaktion = transaktionEinlesen()

    Konto k = new Konto();
    k.addTransaktion(transaktion);

    System.out.println(transaktion.getZeitStempel());
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());

}
```

**PS**: you should not write your code in german. If you aim for a career in programming, you need to get used to English, since that's the standard.

Comment: But if I call the constructor with parameter then they want a local variable for these and I dont want it because the initilization happens in the class menue.